# How to optimize index method with laravel Cache?

Tags: laravel, caching

Is it possible to refactor this method?
What is the best practice to Cache data from database?
Should I do it in Controller or Repository or somewhere else?

```
public function index(Request $request)
  {
    $requestData= trim($request->only(['keyword', 'tag', 'element']));
    $requestData['type']= trim($request->input('type', 'items'));
    $requestData['address'] = trim($request->input('street'.'house'.'corpus'));

    foreach ($requestData as $key => $value) {/* why use loop?*/
      if($key == 'keyword'){/* result without cache*/
         $requestData['field'] = trim($request->input('field', 'title'));
         $data= $this->model->byKeyword($type, $field, $keyword);
         $data['items']= $this->sort($data, $requestData);
      }
      else{
         $data['items'] = Cache::remember($requestData['type'].$key, 10080, function() use ($key, $value) {
        $method = 'by' . $key;
        $data = $this->model->$method($value)->orderBy('premium', 'desc'); 
                $this->sort($data, $requestData);
          });
      }
    }

    if(!$data['items']->first()) { 
      return back()
        ->withInput()
        ->with('status', 'Could not find anything try again!');
     }
    return $this->getView('index/index',$data);
}
```

sort method :

```
public function Sort($data,$request)
{
    $requestData = $request->only(['limitBy', 'sortBy', 'offset', 'limit']);
    $requestData['type'] = $request->input('type', 'items');

//if $requestData == 'limitBy' 

    if($requestData['type'] == 'materials' ||  $requestData['type'] == 'groups')
    {
        $data->whereHas($requestData['type'] == 'groups' ? 'users' : 'user',function($query){
            $query->whereHas('addresses',function($subquery){
                $subquery->whereId( Auth::user()->addresses()->first()->id);
            });
        });
    }else{
        $data->ByExpireDate(
            [Carbon::now(),$requestData['limiBy'] == 'today_expire' ? Carbon::tomorrow() : Carbon::now()->addWeek(1)],
            $requestData['limiBy'] == 'today_expire' ? '1440' : '10080');
    }

//if $requestData == 'limit' 
    $data->where($requestData['limit'],'1');
//if $requestData == 'sortBy' 
    $data->orderBy($requestData['sortBy'],$requestData['direction'] );
//if $requestData == 'offset' 
    $data->skip($requestData['offset'])->take($requestData['limit']);
    return $data->count() > 1 ? $data->paginate(15) : $data->get();
}
```

I have not completed both methods as i dont understand how to refactor it.
First method returns data as i said before,while another one sorts it out.

I think it is not important to fix getView method as it just checks existed files and collect meta :

```
public function getView($path,$data = null)
    {
        logger()->info(__METHOD__);
        if ( ! preg_match('/[^a-z\-_]+/', $path)) {  return 'wrong url';}//add Exception
        if ( ! view()->exists($path)) {              return 'wrong path view';}//add Exception

        $meta  = $this->getMeta($data);
        return view($path,compact('data','meta'));
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to refactor this method?

Yes! Consider the two following points:

1. Could you come back to this code in say 6 months scan through it quickly and understand what it's doing, or a better example... could another developer looking at your code scan through it and understand what the heck is going on? If the answer is no, then sure you can refactor!
2. If you require lots of conditional logic (i.e. your `if` block) then consider simplifying the code for readability, you could try extracting things to methods or if you're performing the same checks over and over again throw it in a loop. Check out the following link also: http://zaengle.com/blog/simplifying-conditional-expressions

Some immediate observations I have about your code are:

- I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do
- Why are you grabbing all of the request data and then doing a huge `if/else if` block **where only one branch will get executed** (I hope you understand this point) why don't you just set up a loop?
- Your indentation is poor around the `if/else if` block which makes it more difficult to understand than it already is (that may be copy and paste into SO though so you can ignore this point if that's the case)

> What is the best practice to Cache data from database?

Never really worked with Caching in Laravel, but consider there are many ways to get the same job done that each have their own advantages. Your best approach should be to weigh up the different options available to you and choose the one that most sense for your application. Check out the different options Laravel supports here in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/cache#configuration

> Should I do it in Controller or Repository or somewhere else?

Again, never really worked with caching in Laravel, but in general if you can separate it into its own class and pull it in when you need it, then do so. Think about the single responsibility principle here, is your controller or repository responsible for caching? If no, then try extracting it out and pulling it in into your controller, or wherever you need it.

**Edit**

> Thank you ! Please could you provide extra help and tell me what do you mean by "just set up a loop"? In the example above i tried to accomplish reading data from repository and shifting the result into cache. I hope you understand my point or my English)Thank you in advance.

Going to go through it step by step, hope this helps!

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    logger()->info(__METHOD__);
    $keyword  = $request->input('keyword');
    $street   = $request->input('street');
    $house    = $request->input('house');
    $corpus   = $request->input('corpus');
    $tag      = $request->input('tag');
    $element  = $request->input('element');
    $field    = $request->input('field', 'title');
    $type     = $request->input('type', 'items');
```

8 lines into one using the only() method, much cleaner!

```
$requestData = $request->only(['keyword', 'street', 'house', 'corpus', 'tag', 'element', 'field', 'type']);
```

Do you really need default values for the last two fields? If so you can do this instead:

```
$requestData = $request->only(['keyword', 'street', 'house', 'corpus', 'tag', 'element']); // only get first 6
$requestData['field'] = $request->input('field', 'title');
$requestData['type'] = $request->input('type', 'items');
```

I have no idea what you're doing here as you're ending the method with the return statement which calls a sort method
your other branches in the if statement all do something with the cache, I think you've done something wrong here?

```
if (isset($keyword)) {
    $data['items'] = $this->model->search($type, $field, $keyword)->orderBy('premium', 'desc');
    return $this->sort($data['items'], $request); // ending the method here!
}
```

If you look at every other branch you're doing practically the same thing

1. call cache remember
2. in the remember callback:

   1. call a method
   2. return sort (why?)

Here are the inner workings of each branch:

```
$data['items'] = Cache::remember($type . $tag, 10080, function() use ($type, $tag, $request) {
    $data = $this->model->byTag($type, $tag)->orderBy('premium', 'desc');
    return $this->sort($data, $request);
});
$data['items'] = Cache::remember($type . $element, 10080, function() use ($type, $element, $request) {
    $data = $this->model->byElement($type, $element)->orderBy('premium', 'desc');
    return $this->sort($data, $request);
});
$data['items'] = Cache::remember($type . $street . $house . $corpus, 10080, function() use ($type, $street, $house, $corpus, $request) {
    $data = $this->model->byAddress($type, $street, $house, $corpus);
    return $this->sort($data, $request);
});
$data['items'] = Cache::remember($type, 10080, function() use ($type, $request) {
    $data = $this->model->byType($type)->orderBy('premium', 'desc');
    return $this->sort($data, $request);
});
```

So to abstract it you want to look at it like this:

```
$data['items'] = Cache::remember(/* keyForCache */, 10080, function() use (/* whatever we need to use */) {
    $data = $this->model->/* methodToCall */(/* request data value */)->orderBy('premium', 'desc');  // don't get what this method is doing at all! Sorry!
    return $this->sort($data, $requestData); // don't get what this method is doing at all! Sorry!
});
```

If I'm honest, your code still doesn't make much sense to me, so I'm just going to make my life simple and make it generic
Let's say you have your request data that looks like this:

```
$requestData = [
    'keyword' => 'some value from request',
    'street'  => 'some value from request',
    'house'   => 'some value from request',
    'corpus'  => 'some value from request',
    'tag'     => 'some value from request',
    'element' => 'some value from request',
    'field'   => 'some value from request',
    'type'    => 'some value from request',
];
```

You could iterate through the array then apply the cache remember function to each item of the array

```
foreach ($requestData as $key => $value) {
    Cache::remember($key, 10080, function() use ($key, $value) {
        $method = 'by' . $key;
        $data = $this->model->$method($value)->orderBy('premium', 'desc'); // shouldn't there be a first or get here?
        return $this->sort($data, $requestData); // don't get what this method is doing at all! Sorry!
    });
}
```

Alternatively you could use Laravel's collections here like this:

```
$collection = collect($requestData);

$collection->each(function ($value, $key) {
    Cache::remember($key, 10080, function() use ($key, $value) {
        $method = 'by' . $key;
        $data = $this->model->$method($value)->orderBy('premium', 'desc'); // shouldn't there be a first or get here?
        return $this->sort($data, $requestData); // don't get what this method is doing at all! Sorry!
    });
});
```

Nicely formatted!

```
if (!$items->first()) { // $items variable is never declated, what!?
    return back()
        ->withInput()
        ->with('status', 'Could not find anything try again!');
}
```

Why do this

```
return $this->getView('index/index', $data);
```

When you can just do this

```
return view('index/index', $data);
```

Also index/index - not a great way to name your files!

```
}
```

Further tips:

1. Consistency in formatting
2. Don't put a whole if statement on one line
3. when method chaining break it up on to multiple lines to make it more readable
4. Separate parameters in a method with a space e.g.:

Don't do this:

```
$this->function($a,$b,$c);
```

Do this:

```
$this->function($a, $b, $c);
```

5. If a method is one word don't use a capital letter for the first letter, e.g.:

Don't do this:

```
$this->model->Search(...)
```

Do this:

```
$this->model->search(...)
```

This won't stop php from processing it AFAIK but it's better for readability

6. Look at PSR-2 coding standards and try and apply them in your code: http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

**Edit 2**

**Sort method**
Going through this line by line...

- Name methods starting with a lower case letter: `sort()`, it's common practice in PHP
- Leave a space between the comma and the next parameter in the method's arguments: `($data, $request)`

  `public function Sort($data,$request)
  {`
- Ideally, you'd pass the request data in rather than relying on the method to deal with that for you, think about how many different things your method is doing and how many it **should** be doing.

  ```
  $requestData = $request->only(['limitBy', 'sortBy', 'offset', 'limit']);
  $requestData['type'] = $request->input('type', 'items');
  ```
- Don't understand what you're trying to do with your code here, sorry!
- Doesn't this line of code:

  `whereHas($requestData['type'] == 'groups' ? 'users' : 'user'`

equate to `whereHas(true/false ...)`, is this even valid code? I'm pretty sure `($requestData['type'] == 'groups')` would return true or false.

```
    if($requestData['type'] == 'materials' ||  $requestData['type'] == 'groups') {
        $data->whereHas($requestData['type'] == 'groups' ? 'users' : 'user', function ($query) {
            $query->whereHas('addresses', function($subquery) {
                $subquery->whereId(Auth::user()->addresses()->first()->id);
            });
        });
    } else {
        $data->ByExpireDate(
            [Carbon::now(),$requestData['limiBy'] == 'today_expire' ? Carbon::tomorrow() : Carbon::now()->addWeek(1)],
            $requestData['limiBy'] == 'today_expire' ? '1440' : '10080');
    }
```

- Sorry but I don't get the rest of it, very confused...

  //if $requestData == 'limit' 
      $data->where($requestData['limit'],'1');
  //if $requestData == 'sortBy' 
      $data->orderBy($requestData['sortBy'],$requestData['direction'] );
  //if $requestData == 'offset' 
      $data->skip($requestData['offset'])->take($requestData['limit']);
      return $data->count() > 1 ? $data->paginate(15) : $data->get();
  }

**getView method**

I would personally not do my error checking here. If it makes sense to you, that's fine! However, Laravel enables you to deal with exceptions in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` read more about it in the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#the-exception-handler.

```
public function getView($path,$data = null)
{
    logger()->info(__METHOD__);
    if ( ! preg_match('/[^a-z\-_]+/', $path)) {  return 'wrong url';}//add Exception
    if ( ! view()->exists($path)) {              return 'wrong path view';}//add Exception

    $meta  = $this->getMeta($data);
    return view($path,compact('data','meta'));
}
```

Try opening a new question to see if you get any response and further help.

Comment: Thank you ! Please could you provide extra help and tell me what do you mean by "just set up a loop"? In the example above i tried to accomplish reading data from repository and shifting the result into cache.I hope you understand my point or my English)Thank you in advance.

Comment: @znack Updated my answer, but I found it really difficult to help directly on your code as I don't understand much of it! Hope it helps anyway!

Comment: Thank you again,It is very helpful. I want to explain why i am using sort and getView methods,so maybe you can help me to refactor both these methods as well.

Comment: First method check if $request->has('sortBy')  fields so it provides additional query->where('filed',$sortBy),while the second one generate meta tags as I don't have currently meta tags in my db.All these methods exist in baseController so every other controller might use it. Looking forward on your opinion about my "smart" way to organize code.Thank you again.

Comment: Sure, update your question and I can try to make some suggestions. Please keep in mind that any answer I give is just from my knowledge, there may be a better way to do it!

Comment: @znack put your method code in your question using edit/update and I will try to offer some suggestions

Comment: Haakym,I tried to fix my code with your suggestions but unfortunately i stacked with loop.In my case I have tried to request data from repository by keyword,by tag name,by element name or by address.Therefore i dont need to gather all at one time,just one request.I put all new code in the question with new sort method as well,Hope to see your opinion about this.Thank you.

Comment: i did update my question.So hope to see you opinion.

Comment: @znack Updated answer. Try opening a new question to see if you get any response and further help.

Comment: @haakym I just upvoted your answer because it was so thoughtful, thorough and kind to a new member.

Comment: @whoacowboy thanks a lot - I don't even remember writing it haha